# movie silent until button press, flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I thought I could change the Boolean true/false value, but it's not working. How do I get this to hush, until the button is pressed?

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var soundOn:Boolean = true; //music is ON when we start
var myToons:TitleMusic = new TitleMusic();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = myToons.play(0,1000); // endless loop, in effect
var myTransform:SoundTransform;

mySoundButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleSound);
mySoundButton.buttonMode = true;
mySoundButton.mouseChildren = false;


function toggleSound(e:MouseEvent)
{
    if(soundOn)
    {
        // turn sound off
        myTransform = new SoundTransform();
        myTransform.volume = 0; // silent
        myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
        soundOn = false;
        mySoundButton.myButtonText.text = "click to turn sound ON";
    }
    else // sound is off
    {
        // turn sound on
        myTransform = new SoundTransform();
        myTransform.volume = 1; // full volume
        myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
        soundOn = true;
        mySoundButton.myButtonText.text = "click to turn sound OFF";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need Boolean statements. Here's what I did.

The variable 'mySound' instantiates the sounds. I hand control of the sound to 'myChannel'. Buttons from the components panel are given there names. Make sure to set up your mp3 properties correctly, Name 'Sound, Class 'Sound'. Everything should work!

**Play and Stop embedded mp3**

```
                /*      
                place mp3 in library. 
                Give it a Name and Class of 'Sound'
                */
        var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
                //control the channel that your sound is on
        var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
playButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, myPlayButtonHandler);
                /*
                Grab a Play and Stop button from the components menu.
                Go to Properties Panel and give each an instance name.
                Play is 'playButton', Stop is 'stopButton'
                */
        function myPlayButtonHandler (e:MouseEvent):void {
                //mySound.play();//use channel instead 
            myChannel = mySound.play();
            }
                //Stopping the sound channel
stopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickStop);
        function onClickStop(e:MouseEvent):void{
            myChannel.stop();
            }
```

**Load external mp3 option**

```
            //URL load and auto play of external file "myMp3.mp3"
            var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
            snd.load(new URLRequest("myMp3.mp3"));
            snd.play();
```

Comment: Thanks, that saved my butt. I couldn't find any tutorials like this. Thanks again:)